# Vue infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use the v-money package to mask a money input field like this:

```
<template v-if="serviceContract.services">
    <tr
        v-for="service in serviceContract.services"
        :key="service.id"
    >
        <td>
            <money
                v-model.trim="service.unit_price_excl_tax"
                v-bind="money"
                @input="calcPricesFromUnitPrice(service)"
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Methods:

```
calcPricesFromUnitPrice(service) {
    // here I do some calculation stuff with that service variable
}
```

I always get the Vue warning

> You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

I have no idea what this means or why it is giving me this warning.

Comment: do you update `service.unit_price_excl_tax` variable from that method?

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis that Money compenent does is automatically since I v-model it there https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-money

Comment: sure, but do you update `unit_price_excl_tax` from `calcPricesFromUnitPrice` also?
This may cause infinite update loop

Comment: yes at some point in the calculation, but it's a bit complex and I cant use data or something since it's a in a loop i can have multiple "service"

Comment: but you got your answer :)